# Как в CSS переносить очень длинное слово по буквам на новую строку?

Tags: css

Есть блок с текстом, в котором есть длинное слово.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью CSS перенести это слово побуквенно на новую строку, чтобы слово не выходило за пределы блока?

Comment: а погуглить Вам просто влом? https://webformyself.com/polnoe-rukovodstvo-po-word-wrap-overflow-wrap-i-word-break-v-css/

Comment: А в реальности такое слово существует ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте свойство [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/word-break), есть несколько свойств, по ссылке есть примеры и описание.

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul li {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>текст текст</li>
  <li>текст текст</li>
  <li>Оченьдлинноеслово</li>
  <li>текст текст</li>
  <li>текст текст</li>
  <li>текст текст</li>
</ul>
```

Чтобы перенос был по буквам, используйте `word-break: break-all;`

---

Так же можно ограничить текст, обрезав "вылезающий" текст и визуально (через троеточие) пометить "продолжение текста", при помощи свойства [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul li {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>текст текст</li>
  <li>текст текст</li>
  <li>Оченьдлинноеслово</li>
  <li>текст текст</li>
  <li>текст текст</li>
  <li>текст текст</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

В стилях для переноса сток используй
word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 0):

С помощью widht: цифра;
Например:

```
p{
   width: 300px; /*То есть строка будет до 300 пикселей*/
}
```

Или

```
<p style="widht: 300px;">
</p>
```

Также можно с помощью `<wbr>` - переносит на новую строку. Почитайте подробнее [Здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/perenosy-slov)